# Spring cloud feign vs open feign

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

As I see there are two options of using feign one of them is open feign and the other one is spring cloud feign which actually uses open feign internally. But I could not find too much information about advantages of each of them. How can we decide to which one to go with, is any of them has advantage over other one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud OpenFeign provides easy integration and utilities for using OpenFeign/Feign in Spring Boot and Spring Cloud applications. If your application is built on top of Spring and Spring Boot, in order to take advantage of those integrations, you might want to choose Spring Cloud OpenFeign. However, since Spring Cloud OpenFeign is in maintenance mode and will no longer be actively developed, you might consider using [Spring Interface Clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/rest-clients.html#rest-http-interface), that are the Spring's own declarative clients solution, instead. If your app is not built on top of Spring Boot, you should use OpenFeign/Feign directly.

Comment: Thank you Olga. I found out your video related to topic on youtube as well.