# How to declare different Oauth2 client registration id's for each feign client?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

Im Using Spring Boot 2.7.2 together with Spring Cloud 2021.0.
I have multiple OAuth2 providers:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          provider-one:
            authorization-uri: https://provider-one/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://provider-one/oauth/token
          provider-two:
            authorization-uri: https://provider-two/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://provider-two/oauth/token
        registration:
          client-one:
            provider: provider-one
            client-id: client-one
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
          client-two:
            provider: provider-two
            client-id: client-two
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
```

We can define the client registration id for spring cloud openfeign:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      oauth2:
        enabled: true
        client-registration-id: client-one
```

But what do I do if I need `FeignClientA` to get a token from `provider-one` and I need `FeignClientB` to get a token from `provider-two`? Is there a configurative way to
achieve that or do I need to set one interceptor for each feign client myself?

Comment: openfeign is one guy's pet project. May not be the best choice.

Comment: What is this statement that *"openfeign is one guy's pet project"* based on? Only the `OAuth2AccessTokenInterceptor` auto-configured by the Cloud Starter is limited to one single client-id in application properties, but OpenFeign integration in Spring is definitely designed to support many clients, each with its own conf if necessary (and [the manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html) contains instruction to register your own `RequestInterceptor` beans globally or per-client)

Comment: @ch4mp frankly speaking, we came to the ~ same conclusion: (open)feign is not suitable for production use

Comment: @andrey-b-panfilov would you please develop? Because I never wrote anything approaching (unless you mean that [a repo with more than 200 contributors](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) is a *"one guy's pet project"* like @k-nicholas?). See my answer below, you can provide a `@FeignClient` with the registration-id you want in a one liner `@Bean` declaration. I really don't see the problem here.

Comment: @ch4mp personally I do like feign for it lightness, unfortunately that is exactly the case when one design fault makes the product completely useless: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/1243

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Isnt that always whats happening? You have certain requirements and you design your product to meet that requirements and after that there is that one or more guys who have a different use case (like the huge file in your example) and you need to adjust your product.

Comment: my responsibility is to anticipate further requirements/issues. does feign support http specification fully? will it cause problems in the future? is it actively maintained? etc...

Comment: Yes. And the question is do you overengineer a product until you have all possible edge case scenarios covered or do you go out with an MVP / MSP and improve it incrementally over time to add more value and more edge cases?

Comment: "overengineering" - it is when you are creating separate spring context per endpoint, like `Spring Cloud OpenFeign` does, or when you are turning very tiny library into a monster which requires spring framework instead of submitting and promoting PRs like `Spring Cloud OpenFeign` does. IRL we may choose between spring's `webclient`, apache's `httpclient` and something more exotic like `jax-rs` or `rest-easy`, feign is out of scope there.

Comment: @andrey-b-panfilov if your criteria for a tool to be production ready is it has no possible feature request, then you might not have many in portfolio. At the end of the day, I use a tool when it saves me time and money (Feign does 90% of the time) and use another one more adapted for edge cases. Or I use extensions like [those I created](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) for OAuth2 in Spring (test authentication and security auto-configuration). Should I consider Spring Security not ready for production because it does not Include these features I wanted?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why I would have a *"separate spring context per endpoin"* . I have one per `@FeignClient` which is a very different cardinality.

Comment: @ch4mp I believe you do not imagine how you are right about spring security: the library, which completely breaks compatibility upon any major update is definitely not production ready

Comment: All this is laughable: 1) Spring Security ihas been successfuly used in production for years by (many) thousands of projects, and 2) this is the convention to bump a major version for breaking changes. A project without changes is not a mature project, it is a dead one.

Comment: how are you dare to lecture me what smells in my projects when you didn't even see them? you would better to pay more attention to yours smells instead:[Optional.ofNullable().flatMap(v -> Optional.ofNullable(v))](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/a1624c95e3214b432215aacf7fc615b12fa30a76/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oidc/starter/synchronised/HttpServletRequestSupport.java#L43C3-L43C77)

Comment: The reason why I modified my preceding comment (before you posted your answer) is precisely because I had not enough information about the code referenced in the ticket you linked and was probably making wrong assumptions on it. Sorry if you had time to read it and if it hurt you. I will never pretend my architecture or code to be perfect (it is frequently not even good), but `optional.flatMap(v -> Optional.ofNullable(v.getNullable())` (as in the line you link) ans `optional.flatMap(v -> Optional.ofNullable(v))` are different statements.

Comment: That said, reading the Javadoc of `HttpServletRequest#getSession`, it seems that it never returns null: apparently, this `getSession()` is not really a getter: it mutates the request to create a session if none is bound to the request yet. So in the case of the code you link, `getRequest().flatMap(req -> Optional.ofNullable(req.getSession()))` could probably be changed to `getRequest().map(HttpServletRequest::getSession)`. I don't know how much resource this would save (and I not sure what I would get as session in a stateless resource server)...

Comment: Those versions of Spring Cloud OpenFeign and Spring Boot are no longer supported, so may expose you to security vulnerabilities; please upgrade to a supported version and get back if you still have OAuth questions .

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek yes we are working on that.

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek aren't OAuth2 auto-configuration and easiest way to select the registrationId for each client the same with `2023.0.x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application properties:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        config:
          feign-client-one:
            url: https://api-one
          feign-client-two:
            url: https://api-two
      oauth2:
        enabled: false
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          provider-one:
            authorization-uri: https://provider-one/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://provider-one/oauth/token
          provider-two:
            authorization-uri: https://provider-two/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://provider-two/oauth/token
        registration:
          registration-one:
            provider: provider-one
            client-id: client-one
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
          registration-two:
            provider: provider-two
            client-id: client-two
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
```

Mind:

- the registration IDs which I changed to make it clearer that the request interceptor instances below reference `registration-id` and not `client-id`
- the disabled default OAuth2 support (which binds to a single client-id)

And then Feign clients with a request interceptor in conf:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "feign-client-one", configuration = FeignClientOne.FeignConfiguration.class)
public interface FeignClientOne {

    static class FeignConfiguration {
        @Bean
        OAuth2AccessTokenInterceptor oauth2AccessTokenInterceptorOne(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
            return new OAuth2AccessTokenInterceptor("registration-one", authorizedClientManager);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@FeignClient(name = "feign-client-two", configuration = FeignClientTwo.FeignConfiguration.class)
public interface FeignClientTwo {

    static class FeignConfiguration {
        @Bean
        OAuth2AccessTokenInterceptor oauth2AccessTokenInterceptorTwo(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
            return new OAuth2AccessTokenInterceptor("registration-two", authorizedClientManager);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Edit: Migrating from `@FeignClient` to `@HttpExchange` proxy with `RestClient`

It seems that `spring-cloud-openfeign` is entering "maintenance" mode. The references I could find about that are [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76375910/619830) from @OlgaMaciaszek and [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/968) on the Github repo.

I explored a bit around the alternative recommended by Olga and liked it enough to add some experimental support for Spring `@HttpExchange` factories to [this starter I maintain](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc) (but be aware that it works only with Boot `3.2.2`):

```java
@HttpExchange(accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public interface ClientOne {

    @GetExchange(url = "/users/count")
    Long getTotalUsersCount(@PathVariable(name = "realm") String realm);

}
```

```java
@HttpExchange(accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public interface ClientTwo {

    @GetExchange(url = "/users/count")
    Long getTotalUsersCount(@PathVariable(name = "realm") String realm);

}
```

```java
@Bean
ClientOne clientOne(SpringAddonsRestClientSupport restSupport) {
    return restSupport.restClientService("client-one", ClientOne.class);
}

@Bean
ClientTwo clientTwo(SpringAddonsRestClientSupport restSupport) {
    return restSupport.restClientService("client-two", ClientTwo.class);
}
```

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          provider-one:
            issuer-uri: https://issuer-one
          provider-two:
            issuer-uri: https://issuer-two
        registration:
          registration-one:
            provider: provider-one
            client-id: client-one
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
          registration-two:
            provider: provider-two
            client-id: client-two
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        client:
          rest:
            client-one:
              base-uri: http://localhost:7081
              auth2-registration-id: registration-one
            client-two:
              base-uri: http://localhost:7082
              auth2-registration-id: registration-two
```

If you don't want to use "my" starter, you can have a look at [`BearerTokenAuthenticationInterceptor`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oidc/starter/rest/BearerTokenAuthenticationInterceptor.java) and [`AuthorizedClientBearerProvider`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oidc/starter/rest/AuthorizedClientBearerProvider.java) for the `RequestInterceptor` impl and then at [`SpringAddonsRestClientSupport`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oidc/starter/rest/SpringAddonsRestClientSupport.java) for the `RestClient` configuration and `@Service` proxying.

Comment: thx. and you also added feign ulr configuration which is supported in later versions of spring cloud. I guess it was a 2022 release.

Comment: @Mulgard I just noticed that the `@Configuration` annotations are not necessary on the configuration classes referenced by `@FeignClient`. Maybe it is even preferable not to put it to prevent it to be accidentally applied to other clients. I updated my answer to remove it.

Comment: @Mulgard it seems that spring-cloud-openfeign is entering maintenance mode. When you're ready to upgrade to latest Spring version, you might be interested in the edit I just added.